# Laplacian OpenCV Android not working

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to use Laplacian in my app:

```
Bitmap result = source.copy(source.getConfig(), true);
Utils.bitmapToMat(source, in);
Imgproc.Laplacian(in, out, 3, 3, 1, 0);
Utils.matToBitmap(out, result);
```

But I get the following error:

```
E/cv::error()﹕ OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.type() == CV_8UC1 || src.type() == CV_8UC3 || src.type() == CV_8UC4) in void Java_org_opencv_android_Utils_nMatToBitmap2(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong, jobject, jboolean)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/android/Utils.html#matToBitmap(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20Bitmap,%20boolean)) `Utils.matToBitmap` accepts only `Mat` of `CV_8U` depth. In your example you specify output depth to `CV_16S`. You should specify output depth for `Imgproc.Laplacian`, as follows:

```
Imgproc.Laplacian(in, out, CvType.CV_8U, 3, 1, 0); 
Utils.matToBitmap(out, result);
```

See [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#Laplacian(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20int,%20int,%20double,%20double,%20int)) for Laplacian.